# Scala access inherited static member of Java class

Tags: java, scala

Consider the following classes:

```
//A.java:
public interface A {
    public static final String HIGHER = "higher";
}

//B.java:
public class B implements A {
    public static final String LOWER = "lower";
}
```

In java code I have access to both HIGHER and LOWER fields:

```
//JavaClient.java:
public class JavaClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(B.HIGHER);
        System.out.println(B.LOWER);
    }
}
```

But I cannot do the same thing in Scala!

```
//ScalaClient.scala:
object ScalaClient {
  def main (args: Array[String]) {
    println(B.HIGHER)    // Compilation error
    println(B.LOWER)     // OK
  }
}
```

This is very unexpected for me. Why Scala cannot see inherited psf field? How to workaround?

**Note**: In my real code I don't have access to interface A, since it is protected and nested in another class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix the problem in two ways.

1) Just remove the `static` word in interface A & interface B and it should work.

Or

2) Create a trait (*trait is a feature in Scala, which closely resembles java interface but there are many differences*)

```
trait A { }

object A { 
  final val Higher = "higher"
}
```

Now you can access `A.Higher` from your caller Scala class.

Comment: This answer is simply wrong. 1) Removing `static` will cause compilation error, since interfaces can't have non-`static` fields; 2) If it didn't, it would change the meaning of the code; 3) Scala can access Java's `static` members.

Comment: Below code is compiling (removing static for variable declaration in interface) : interface A{
    public final String HIGHER = "higher";
}

Comment: Because fields in interfaces are implicitly `static` - you literally can't make a non-static field in plain Java.

Comment: Yes, Since it is implicit, no need to mention it as explicit.

Comment: I came to solution like suggested by you: 

    object C extends A {
       final val EXPOSE = A.HIGHER
    }

Comment: Ah sorry, didn't remember this. In this case, of course, removing `static` won't work because it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 3):

Just access `HIGHER` as `A.HIGHER`. So far as Scala is concerned, `static` members in Java are members of companion objects, and the companion object of `B` doesn't extend the companion object of `A`: that's why you can't use `B.HIGHER`.

> Note: In my real code I don't have access to interface A, since it is protected and nested in another class.

In this case, however, you have a problem. The one thing I can think of is to expose the constant explicitly from Java code, e.g. (assuming you can change `B`):

```
public class B implements A {
    public static final String LOWER = "lower";
    public static final String HIGHER1 = HIGHER;
}
```

Comment: I like this approach : public static final String HIGHER1 = HIGHER

Comment: Actually, I don't have access to B either.

Comment: Then defining new trait is good option instead of using java interface for those constants.

Comment: @Nyavro Then you can expose it in some other class in the same way.

Comment: @ravindra The problem with defining a new trait is that if the constant changes in Java code, you have to notice and change it in your Scala code as well.